# How to display the last item of a CarouselView when it is loaded?

Tags: c#, data-binding, carousel, maui

I'm developing an app and I'm facing an issue with the CarouselView in .NET MAUI.

When the Carousel is launched, there is the disposition (white squares are images):
[image]

I want, when the application starts, this disposition:
[image]

I tried some properties like `PeekAreaInsets` or `HeightRequest` but nothing changed.

This is my XAML :

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <CarouselView x:Name="carrouselView" ItemsSource="{Binding Publications}" 
                  HorizontalOptions="Start" IndicatorView="indicatorView" 
                  PeekAreaInsets="100" FlowDirection="MatchParent" 
                  HeightRequest="350" CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentPublication}"  >
        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="10" />
        </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="DTO:Publication" >
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="CurrentItem">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                   <Setter Property="Scale" Value="1.3"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PreviousItem">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Scale" Value="0.8"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NextItem">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Scale" Value="0.8"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                      <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource byteToImageSourceConverter}}" 
                             HeightRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModels:MainPageViewModel}}, Path=DisplayPopupCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                   IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                   SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkSlateGray"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</StackLayout>
```

This is part of the ViewModel:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<Publication> publications = new ObservableCollection<Publication>();

[ObservableProperty]
Publication currentPublication = new Publication();

private async Task LoadDailyPublication()
{
    var publicationSQLite = await _serviceToPublication.GetAllAsync();
    if (publicationSQLite.Any(p => DateTime.Compare(p.DateEvent, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) > 0))
        Publications = new ObservableCollection<Publication>(Mapper<Model.SQLite.Publication, Model.DTO.Publication>.Map(publicationSQLite));
    else
    {
        var categoriePublication = await _serviceToCategoriePublication.GetByName("Programme de la semaine");
        List<Publication> publications = await _serviceFromPublication.GetWeeklyPublication(categoriePublication);
        await _serviceToPublication.DeleteAllWeeklyPublication(categoriePublication.CategoriePublicationId);
        await _serviceToPublication.InsertAll(Mapper<Model.DTO.Publication, Model.SQLite.Publication>.Map(publications));
        Publications = new ObservableCollection<Publication>(publications);
        CurrentPublication = Publications.ElementAt(1);
    }
}
```

Do you have some tips about that ?

Comment: Set the CurrentItem property

Comment: It doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Comment: The XAML is in the question. Do you want the ViewModel ?

Comment: You should show the ViewModel, indeed. Are you using an `ObservableCollection` as the `ItemsSource`?

Comment: I want to see any code related to setting the `CurrentItem` property

Comment: I put the part of the viewmodel related to the CurrentItem property in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to programmatically set the currently presented item of a [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview):

## 1. Set `CurrentItem` property

This can either be done in the code-behind or in the ViewModel.

### Option A: Code-behind

Provided that you've set the `x:Name` property of the CarouselView, e.g. to `MyCarousel`:

**XAML**

```xml
<CarouselView
    x:Name="MyCarousel"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">

    <!-- ... -->

</CarouselView>
```

**Code-behind**

```cs
public class SomePage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly SomeViewModel _viewModel;

    public SomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new SomeViewModel();
    }

    private void UpdateCurrentItem()
    {
        // note: this assumes that the data is already loaded in the ViewModel
        MyCarousel.CurrentItem = _viewModel.MyItems.Last();
    }
}
```

### Option B: Data Binding

It can also be done in the ViewModel and then you'll bind to the respective property, e.g. `SelectedItem`:

**ViewModel**

```cs
public partial class SomeViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<SomeItem> _myItems;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private SomeItem _selectedItem;

    public async Task LoadItemsAsync()
    {
        var items = await _someApi.GetItemsAsync();
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<SomeItems>(items);
        SelectedItem = MyItems.Last();
    }
}
```

In your XAML, you'll then bind to the `SelectedItem`:

**XAML**

```xml
<CarouselView
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
    CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">

    <!-- ... -->

</CarouselView>
```

## 2. Set `Position` property

Alternatively, you can use the index of the item instead of the object reference, which can be useful when you don't know which object to go to but you know which index you need to show.

Again, there are the same two ways to do this:

### Option A: Code-behind

Provided that you've set the `x:Name` property of the CarouselView, e.g. to `MyCarousel`:

**XAML**

```xml
<CarouselView
    x:Name="MyCarousel"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">

    <!-- ... -->

</CarouselView>
```

**Code-behind**

```cs
public class SomePage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly SomeViewModel _viewModel;

    public SomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new SomeViewModel();
    }

    private void UpdateCurrentItem()
    {
        // note: this assumes that the data is already loaded in the ViewModel
        MyCarousel.Position = _viewModel.Count - 1;
    }
}
```

### Option B: Data Binding

It can also be done in the ViewModel and then you'll bind to the respective property, e.g. `SelectedIndex`:

**ViewModel**

```cs
public partial class SomeViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<SomeItem> _myItems;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _selectedIndex;

    public async Task LoadItemsAsync()
    {
        var items = await _someApi.GetItemsAsync();
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<SomeItems>(items);
        SelectedIndex = MyItems.Count - 1;
    }
}
```

In your XAML, you'll then bind to the `SelectedIndex`:

**XAML**

```xml
<CarouselView
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
    Position="{Binding SelectedIndex}">

    <!-- ... -->

</CarouselView>
```

## Note

At the time of writing, both ways seem to be broken.

There are two bugs filed in the official GitHub repository:

- [CarouselView doesn't scroll to the CurrentItem when set](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7575)
- [CarouselView position ignored](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14569)

There is a functioning workaround, which is mentioned in issue #7575:

> If I start a new thread and add a delay of 1 second, and then I set the CurrentItem, the CarouselView scrolls correctly to the selected CurrentItem.

In order to make this work, there apparently must be a delay of 1-2 seconds after initially setting up the View and the bindings, this can be achieved using `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));` before setting the new `CurrentItem` or updating the `Position` property, for example.